# How to multiple render radio buttons inside table

Tags: asp.net, datatable, webforms

I have a web form app and one page has this form with 5 questions with multiple choices as radio buttons as shown on the photo. I have to get questions from the DB, header values and bind radio button values with DB fields. The DB part is actually solved, now I tried to render this as DataTable, but it seems to me that DT only renders text, I have no idea how to render radio button inside of it.

Any sugestions are welcome. Also, I have to dynamically add these radio buttons from codebehind.

Basically, I need to display the value inside the table (fetched from DB), and also to read that value later on, to store the response. So far, it seems that the best option is to use GridView instead of DataTable, but I still need help on how to render aspx controls inside individual cells.

[image]

Comment: I'd actually use a Repeater as it gives you a lot more flexibility in styling.

Comment: What language are you writing in? C# or VB?

Comment: You can dynamically build each row, including adding buttons, using the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView.

Comment: I am using C#. I have no idea on how to create a radiobutton using RadioButton constructor, and render it later on from code behind, to some specific place such as table cell. The example from MSDN documentation does not have any controls rendered by repeater, but plain text, which I've managed to create, but radioButtons still are an issue.

Comment: @JohnPete22 OK so far I have two repeaters doing what they should but when I nest them, the other one is not showing

Comment: It would be helpful if you post all code/html for reference.  But what's actually dynamic about the form? Are Question1,2,3, etc... dynamic? The Not Good, Good, etc.. dynamic too?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is some code for you.  This should give you a decent blueprint on how to continue.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="_testPWforSO.aspx.cs" Inherits="_testPWforSO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTest_DataBinding" EnableViewState="true">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="border-color: #CCCCCC; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Not Good</th>
                            <th>Somewhat Good</th>
                            <th>Good</th>
                            <th>Very Good</th>
                            <th>Excellent</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="notGood" runat="server" name="option" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="somewhatGood" runat="server" name="option" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="good" runat="server" name="option" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="veryGood" runat="server" name="option" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="excellent" runat="server" name="option" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    <hr />
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>

        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _testPWforSO :  System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Collection<string> questions = new Collection<string>() { "Test Question 1", "Test Question 2", "Test Question 3" };
            rptTest.DataSource = questions;
            rptTest.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void rptTest_DataBinding(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            string row = Convert.ToString(e.Item.DataItem);

            if (row != null)
            {
                Label question = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestion");

                if (question != null)
                {
                    question.Text = row;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you'd probably want some validation on the radio buttons to ensure they've been clicked, either server or client side
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem row in rptTest.Items)
            {
                if (row.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || row.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    // need to look up the radio buttons. If you used an Asp:RadioButton or something else, it'll probably be easier, but generic <input type='radio'> offer better styling options
                    HtmlInputRadioButton notGood = (HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("notGood");
                    if (notGood != null && notGood.Checked)
                    {
                        // do something, and then continue to next row
                        continue;
                    }


                }
            }

            // either save data and then rebind new questions, or do something else
            Collection<string> questions = new Collection<string>() { "Test Question 4", "Test Question 5", "Test Question 6" };
            rptTest.DataSource = questions;
            rptTest.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            // display error
        }
    }
}
```

I just used a `Collection<string>` for the questions, and thats why I casted to a string in the DataBinding. If you're passing in a different object, then obviously you'd cast to that object.